How to make TypeScript not complain about Iterator.prototype.take()?
I want to use Iterator.prototype.take() in my code but TypeScript keeps complaining it doesn't exist even though in runtime everything works as expected.

Property 'take' does not exist on type 'Generator<number, void, unknown>'

Here is the full code (playground link):
function* rangeFrom<T>(arr: T[]) {
  let count = 0
  let i = 0

  while (true) {
    const value = arr[i]!
    yield value;

    count += 1
    i = i === arr.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1
  }
}

const iterable = rangeFrom([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
console.log(...iterable.take(8))

I couldn't find anything about generator functions in TypeScript. Also tried adding every possible ESNext feature to compilerOptions.lib array in tsconfig.json but that didn't help.
I feel like i am missing something super obvious but can't figure out what exactly.

Your own playground example works fine when you set the lib to esnext as shown here. So this doesn't seem to be a [mre]. What version of TS are you using?

Can you elaborate what exactly did you change in the playground to make it work? The playground i linked already has module set to ESNext but i can't find any lib options there.

Alright, i just needed to change Module to something other than ESNext and then set it back to make it work in the playground. And in my project i needed to upgrade typescript from 5.5.4 to 5.6.3.

The problem was the version of TypeScript i was using which was 5.5.4. After upgrading to 5.6.3 the problem went away. TypeScript 5.6 announcement blog post mentions adding support for iterator helper methods here.
